# Why is Stimulus reading passed number values as strings instead of numbers?

Tags: javascript, liquid, stimulusjs

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to pass number values from HTML (liquid) to Stimulus, but Stimulus is reading them as strings why is this happening?

The values are being pulled from an API, the relevant JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "min": 1,
  "max": 5,
  "value": 3,
}
```

I'm passing `value`, `max`, and `min` to my input component's controller like so:

```
<input type="text"
           id="{{ id }}"
           name="{{ id }}"
           min="{{ min }}"
           max="{{ max }}"
           value="{{ value }}"
           pattern="\d*"
           data-selector-target="selector"
           data-selector-value="{{ value }}"
           data-selector-min="{{ min }}"
           data-selector-max="{{ max }}"
           class="selector p-1 w-9 text-center">
```

And I'm reading the values within my controller. If I console log the values, like in `test()` below:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {

  static targets = ['selector'];
  static values = {
    value: Number,
    min: Number,
    max: Number
  }

  test() {

    console.log({
      value: this.selectorTarget.value,
      typeofvalue: typeof(this.selectorTarget.value),
      min: this.selectorTarget.min,
      typeofmin: typeof(this.selectorTarget.min),
      max: this.selectorTarget.max,
      typeofmax: typeof(this.selectorTarget.max)})

  }

}
```

I get the following results in my console:

```
​value: "3"
typeofValue: "string"
min: "1"
typeofMin: "string"
max: "5"
typeofMax: "string"
​
```

Does anyone know why that's happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you typed your `<input>` to text.

If you want it to consider the values as **Numbers**, then you have to type it so.

```
<input type="number">
```

Comment: we can't use type="number" cos the scroll changing the numbers is inaccessible

Comment: Did YOU made it inaccessible or is it a problem you have?

Comment: no native "number"'s default functionality of changing the number when scrolling is inaccessible by default, because users can accidentally change the number when scrolling and mistakenly submit incorrect numbers

Comment: Well I anwsered your first question.

If you don't want to have a "number" typed input, you could use a selector.

<select id="{{ id }}"
                    name="{{ id }}"
                    data-selector-target="selector">
                {% for val in range(min, max) %}
                    {% if val == value %}
                        <option value="{{ val }}" selected>{{ val }}</option>
                    {% else %}
                        <option value="{{ val }}">{{ val }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the attributes you want (min, max, value) on the HTMLInputElement are always returned as string.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

The `selectorTarget` is a simple HTMLInputElement (according to your HTML and JS code). There is nothing StimulusJS can do about it.

`data-selector-*-value` attributes are to be defined on the controller element. See: https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/values

If you want to access the min, max and value from the Controller, add the values to the controller element.
E.g:

```
<div data-controller="selector"
     data-selector-value="{{ value }}"
     data-selector-min="{{ min }}"
     data-selector-max="{{ max }}">
<input type="text"
           id="{{ id }}"
           name="{{ id }}"
           min="{{ min }}"
           max="{{ max }}"
           value="{{ value }}"
           pattern="\d*"
           data-selector-target="selector"
           class="selector p-1 w-9 text-center">
</div>
```

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {

  static targets = ['selector'];
  static values = {
    value: Number,
    min: Number,
    max: Number
  }

  test() {

    console.log({
      value: this.valueValue,
      typeofvalue: typeof(this.valueValue),
      min: this.minValue,
      typeofmin: typeof(this.minValue),
      max: this.maxValue,
      typeofmax: typeof(this.maxValue)})

  }

}
```

Or you can use the Controller on you input element:

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {

  static values = {
    value: Number,
    min: Number,
    max: Number
  }

  test() {

    console.log({
      value: this.valueValue,
      typeofvalue: typeof(this.valueValue),
      min: this.minValue,
      typeofmin: typeof(this.minValue),
      max: this.maxValue,
      typeofmax: typeof(this.maxValue)})

  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text"
           id="{{ id }}"
           name="{{ id }}"
           min="{{ min }}"
           max="{{ max }}"
           value="{{ value }}"
           pattern="\d*"
           data-controller="selector"
           data-selector-value="{{ value }}"
           data-selector-min="{{ min }}"
           data-selector-max="{{ max }}"
           class="selector p-1 w-9 text-center">
```